# Trouble with changing the font size

Tags: java, android

HI everyone, 
             I am trying to allow my user to change the font size(increase or decrease) in my activity's EditText by pushing a button in the action bar. I have gotten the font size increase to work but for some reason the font size decrease button makes the font size increase as well.

I am attaching (what I think is) the relevant code. Let me know if you need to see anyother buts of code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.TEXT_UP:
            doTextUp();
            break;
        case R.id.TEXT_DOWN:
            doTextDown();
            break;
         default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return false;
        }




private void doTextDown() {
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
    float Textsize = mBodyText.getTextSize() - 1;
    mBodyText.setTextSize(Textsize);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in the text down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void doTextUp() {
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
    float Textsize = mBodyText.getTextSize() + 1;
    mBodyText.setTextSize(Textsize);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in the text up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: getTextSize() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize() gets the size in pixels- so decrementing 1 isn't going to make a difference (literally in the case of many devices). Try decrementing by more, or use a different measurement! Let me know if that's not the problem first, then we can look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing both to:

```
mBodyText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Textsize);
```

`getTextSize()` returns the size in pixels but `setTextSize(float size)` interprets it as a "scaled pixel" (sp) unit. To specify pixels you need to use `setTextSize (int unit, float size)`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTextSize%28%29)
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28float%29)

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, i can not finda problem in the piece of code you provided. I am pretty sure, that your problem comes from a copy past (we programmers are usualy lazy... when we do a copy past it often happens that we forget to change a variable name and we end up with these problems). Look at the event listener on your buttons and see if youdid set up both item cases you have (text_up) and (text_down).